# str_pad using value from phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, sql

I have a field in phpMyAdmin table with integer value example '21'.
I want to update the field example value to '0000021'.
On php script, i select the field and use function str_pad.

```
$sqlc = "SELECT home_number FROM Home";
$values = $dbcon->query($sqlc);
$values = str_pad( $values, 7, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT );
echo $values;
```

But it does not work. $values is not holding any value. I try to print it first, but there is no output appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting no results because `$values` is a result object, not the actual value from the table. To get the actual value, you need to fetch it first. Assuming you are using `mysqli`, something like this:

```
$sqlc = "SELECT home_number FROM Home";
if ($result = $dbcon->query($sqlc)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $values = $row['home_number'];
        $values = str_pad( $values, 7, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT );
        echo $values;
    }
}
```

Note I've added a check to ensure that the query succeeds before attempting to fetch the values. I've also added code to loop over all the results (otherwise if you have more than one row in your table you will only see one result).

For PDO, just replace `$result->fetch_assoc()` in the code above with `$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: Please add error handling (at least for `query()`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what if i am using pdo? Sorry, i still learning to using pdo. @Nick

Comment: @Malca no worries at all - it's just a minor change to the code. See my edit

Comment: Hi @Nick, for example i want to update a field 'home_id' with $values. Can i do code like this? `$sqlrun = "UPDATE Home SET home_id = $values"; $res = $dbcon->query($sqlrun);`

Comment: @Malca once you have got your `$values` from the above code, you can do that, but note that you need to enclose `$value` in quotes otherwise you won't retain the leading zeros e.g. `$sqlrun = "UPDATE Home SET home_id = '$values'";`